# MySQL too many processes and Consuming RAM

Tags: mysql, ram, linux-mint

[image]

I am suddenly having this problem of too many mysqld processes.
When my PC starts the occupied RAM is around 2GB and then when I start XAMPP, slowly and gradually the RAM is occupied at around 14 GB. I currently am running on a 16 GB Memory and using Linux Mint.
Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the config file for MySQL, lower `max_connections` to, say, 20.  That setting is what controls the list you are seeing.

Meanwhile, how much RAM can you give to MySQL?  That is, how much RAM do you need to give to other processes?  What is the value of `innodb_buffer_pool_size`?  The buffer_pool grows until it reaches that value.  It is very important for performance, so it is a tradeoff between performance and running out of RAM.  Lowering the buffer_pool setting is the primary way to shrink MySQL.

(Questions on configuring MySQL belong in dba.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 0):

first update server(for centos: yum update)
anden set this value on your my.cnf file in /etc
innodb_buffer_pool_size => 70% or 80% of your ram

innodb_buffer_pool_size = innodb_buffer_pool_chunk_size * innodb_buffer_pool_instances * N

example for 6G ram:

```
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 4294967296
innodb_buffer_pool_chunk_size = 1073741824
innodb_buffer_pool_instances = 4
```